# Ambiguous match error in cucumber step definitions

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

In my cucumber step definitions I have the following

```
Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |text|
   page.should have_content(text)
end

Then /^I should see "(.*?)" within "(.*?)"$/ do |text,css|
   within(css) do
      page.should have_content(text)
   end
end
```

This causes an "Ambiguous Match" error by cucumber when I run the features. I can work around this error by passing the **--guess** flag to cucumber. But I'm wondering why cucumber is finding ambiguity in the above two step definitions when both are clearly different. Is there any way to make it work without using the --guess option ?

Thanks

Comment: Similar but not identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699284/how-to-match-these-steps-unambiguously-in-cucumber-jvm/24699747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step matches everything the second step does. Even with the non-greedy modifier, `".*?"` matches `"foo" within "bar"`. Fix it like this:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |text|
   page.should have_content(text)
end
```